# Pass a variable to an arrow function

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm working with puppeteer, and I'm trying to pass a variable to an arrow function like this

```
    const token ='qwertyuisdfghjkl';

    await page.evaluate(token => {
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    });
```

But `token` is `undefined`

Comment: The `page.evaluate()` function is the thing that has to pass the parameter.

Comment: which `token` you want to use ? the one declared with `const` or the one in callback?

Comment: You haven't called page.evaluate method. You need to call it with some parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) say to pass the value as the second parameter:

```
const token = 'qwertyuisdfghjkl'

await page.evaluate(value => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", value)
}, token)
```

Comment: Dawn I came here to say the same thing :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass as variable as second argument in `page.evaluate`

```
const token ='qwertyuisdfghjkl';

await page.evaluate(value => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", value);
}, token);
```

[`Docs`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

Comment: A string can also be used: `page.evaluate(\`localStorage.setItem("token", ${token})\`)`

Comment: I get ` token is not defined` like this